# Image of subgroup under canonical projection

Tags: group-theory

Define: $\phi:G \to G/N$ where $N$ is normal in $G$. Take $H \le G$. How to show that its image is isomorphic to $HN/N$? I know I should show $Img(H)$ isomorphic to $H/(H \cap N)$ somehow. But I can't see how to show that either. Any idea?

Comment: Do you remember what the First Isomorphism Theorem says? If you can show that $H \cap N$ is the kernel of the restriction of $\phi$ to $H$, then you will essentially be done by what you've said so far.

Comment: @Daniel Li: Do you know the correspondence theorem in group theory? Check it out: what exactly does it say? Note that $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $H$.